# c++ syntax of create an instance

Tags: c++, class

```
class class_name instance;

class_name instance;
```

The above all work with `cl.exe`, but is it standard,is it the same with all other compilers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class class_name instance;` is allowed by the [*elaborated-type-specifier*](http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppgrammar.html#elaborated-type-specifier) nonterminal in the C++ grammar. It's hard to point to a particular section of the standard that tells you this, since even in the appendix that gives the C++ grammar it's rather spread out, but the production basically goes (with many steps elided):

```
declaration-statement
    -> type-specifier declarator ;
    -> elaborated-type-specifier declarator ;
    -> class identifier declarator ;
    -> class identifier unqualified-id ;
    -> class class_name instance ;
```

`class_name instance ;`, in comparison, is produced using the [`simple-type-specifier`](http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppgrammar.html#simple-type-specifier) non-terminal.

```
declaration-statement
    -> type-specifier declarator ;
    -> simple-type-specifier declarator ;
    -> type-name unqualified-id ;
    -> class_name instance ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's standard and means the same thing. `class T` and `T` mean the same thing in C++. The syntax comes from C where `struct T` and `T` don't mean the same thing.